# c# - how do I order a list of 4 Points by clockwise order (tl, tr, br, bl) for use in opencv getPerspective?

Tags: c#, python, arrays, sorting, opencv

I am using opencv in c# to detect contours in a webcam image. If the contour has 4 points, I want to use it to correct the perspective of the pixels contained within this contour using opencv's `getPerspective` and `warpPerspective`. functions.

Here is the code to get those 4 points:

```
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(perimMat,polyMat,0.005 * perim, true); //get contour of the current detected perimeter as polyMat
    List<Point> polyMatList = polyMat.toList(); //convert it to a list of points
    if (polyMatList.Count == 4){ //this contour has 4 points, we can use it for getting perspective
      Debug.Log("p1x: " + polyMatList[0].x + "p1y: " + polyMatList[0].y); //example log: p1x: 203,p1y: 111
    }
```

So now that I have this list of points, I need to make sure it is ordered top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left so I can use it in `getPerspective`. How do I do this?

I've seen examples in other languages, but they usually use something like numpy to do the sorting. I'm a bit unfamiliar with C# (using it because of Unity), but I'm assuming there are some helper methods I can draw from somehow.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/nikgens/1a129d620978a4abc6a9a30f5f66e0d3) has been my primary guide for adjusting perspective so far, and the `for_point_warp` function seems to provide a decent guide. I just don't know the c# equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I implemented, based off of [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/) (though I'm sure I could do something more elegant).

```
polyMat.convertTo(orientationMat, CvType.CV_32S); //conver MatOfPoint2f back to MatofPoint so it can be drawn
//sort by y val

polyMatList = polyMatList.OrderBy(p => p.x).ToList();

List<Point> leftmostPts = new List<Point>();
leftmostPts.Add(polyMatList[0]);
leftmostPts.Add(polyMatList[1]);

List<Point> rightmostPts = new List<Point>();
rightmostPts.Add(polyMatList[2]);
rightmostPts.Add(polyMatList[3]);

//we now have a top left point
leftmostPts = leftmostPts.OrderBy(p => p.y).ToList();

//calculate distance from top left to rightmost 2 points:
double dX0 = rightmostPts[0].x - leftmostPts[0].x;
double dY0 = rightmostPts[0].y - leftmostPts[0].y;
double d0 = Math.Sqrt(dX0 * dX0 + dY0 * dY0); 

double dX1 = rightmostPts[1].x - leftmostPts[0].x;
double dY1 = rightmostPts[1].y - leftmostPts[0].y;
double d1 = Math.Sqrt(dX1 * dX1 + dY1 * dY1);

List<Point> orderedPolyMat = new List<Point>();
orderedPolyMat.Add(leftmostPts[0]);
if (d0 > d1){ //greatest distance between right two points will be bottom right
    orderedPolyMat.Add(rightmostPts[1]);
    orderedPolyMat.Add(rightmostPts[0]);
} else {
    orderedPolyMat.Add(rightmostPts[0]);
    orderedPolyMat.Add(rightmostPts[1]);
}
orderedPolyMat.Add(leftmostPts[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
//Begin by sorting your list by y values using List.sort()

polyMatList.sort( (pnt_a, pnt_b) => pnt_b.y - pnt_a.y ); // points 0 & 1 will by definition be your top points and points 2, 3 will be definition be your bottom points.

// now your top 2 points may be out of order since we only sorted by y in the previous step
Point tempPoint;

if(polyMatList[0].x > polyMatList[1].x)
{
   tempPoint = polyMatList[0];
   polyMatList[0] = polyMatList[1];
   polyMatList[1] = tempPoint ;
}

// same goes for your bottom two points 
if(polyMatList[2].x > polyMatList[3].x)
{
   tempPoint = polyMatList[2];
   polyMatList[2] = polyMatList[3];
   polyMatList[3] = tempPoint ;
}

//now your list will be ordered tl, tr, bl, br
```

Comment: I don't think this is working properly. I'm logging values and they are not appearing in the right order: `0: {97, 176}, 1: {333, 156}, 2: {98, 424}, 3: {341, 431}`

Comment: change polyMatList.sort( (pnt_a, pnt_b) => pnt_a.y - pnt_b.y  ) 
to polyMatList.sort( (pnt_a, pnt_b) => pnt_b.y - pnt_a.y) now the points with the largest y values will appear at the start of the list. Note the method outlined in my answer may not handle degenerate cases well e.g. {(-1,0) ( 0,1) (1,0) (0,-1)}. You can detect this case by checking if the middle 2 elements have the same Y value after sorting by y. In this case you should order the middle 2 elements by x value immediately after the call to polyMatList.sort.